# @NotNull annotation does not translate to not null constraint in schema generation

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator, hibernate-5.x, mysql-5.5

According to hibernate validator reference documentation - Section **11.1.1. Database schema-level validation** (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-checkconstraints-db),

> Out of the box, Hibernate ORM will translate the constraints you have
>   defined for your entities into mapping metadata. For example, if a
>   property of your entity is annotated @NotNull, its columns will be
>   declared as not null in the DDL schema generated by Hibernate ORM.

But when I annotate my fields with @NotNull, I'm not getting the schema level constraints automatically.

I tried setting `Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO` to `update` and `create` but neither one works in generating the database constraints.

Even though hibernate by default has the `hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl` set to `true`, I even tried setting that manually -

```
settings.put("hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl", true);
```

But none of these options seems to work for me.

My domain class

```
package com.praveen.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Stakeholder extends MyPersistent {

    @NotNull
    private String clientCode;

    @NotNull
    private String gender;
}
```

MyPersistent class

```
package com.praveen.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyPersistent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

The code I'm using to get the session factory is

```
    private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

                Map<String, Object> settings = new HashMap<>();
                settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, Driver.class.getName());
                settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_test?"
                        + "zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&"
                        + "createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&"
                        + "useSSL=true&"
                        + "verifyServerCertificate=false&"
                        + "autoReconnect=true");
                settings.put(Environment.USER, "root");
                settings.put(Environment.PASS, "");
                settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, MySQL55Dialect.class);
                settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
                settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, false);

                // HikariCP settings
                settings.put("hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout", "20000");
                settings.put("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle", "5");
                settings.put("hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize", "20");
                settings.put("hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout", "300000");

                registryBuilder.applySettings(settings);
                registry = registryBuilder.build();
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);
                sources.addAnnotatedClass(Stakeholder.class);

                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                shutdown();
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Comment: @Kayaman, I referred that post before I posted my own, and it clearly states "As Hibernate is the reference implementation of JSR 303, however, it intelligently picks up on these constraints and translates them into database constraints for you, so you get two for the price of one". But for some reason it didn't work out for me, and I'm asking why.

Comment: To be clear, is this a case where you're creating a new schema from a blank database, or are you trying to get Hibernate to apply the constraints to an existing schema?

Comment: I tried both scenarios but the result is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a silly mistake on my side as I hadn't included the `javax.el` dependency and its implementation in the pom.xml.

Interestingly enough, I didn't get the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager` error by then as I hadn't written any code to initialize the `ValidatorFactory` by `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()`.

As soon as I wrote the code and used `ValidatorFactory`, I got the `NoClassDefFoundError` and found out I was missing the `javax.el` dependency.

So finally I was able to resolve the `NoClassDefFoundError` error as well as the non translation issue of validation annotations to database constraints in schema generation by adding the below dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use 
@Column(nullable = false)

@NotNull is for Bean validation, not schema constraints, and if you are using an older version of hibernate @NotNull will not be translated to column constraint

Comment: I'm using the latest stable versions :-

hibernate-core - 5.3.1 
hibernate-validator - 6.0.10
javax.persistence-api - 2.2
validation-api-2.0.1

Comment: maybe it's worth trying anyway to narrow down the problem

Comment: FYI: using @NotNull is recommended by Hibernate guide, see hint at the end of this chapter: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#basic-attributes